# hibernate Validator not validating model class

Tags: spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

This question has been asked a lot of times, even after going through all the solutions i wansn't able to get hibernate validator working.

> Controller class:-

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/setReg"},method={RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST})
public ModelAndView setRegistration( @Valid @ModelAttribute("userDetails") UserDetails userDetails,BindingResult bindingResult){
logger.info("setRegistration :Entry");
if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
logger.info("binding success"); 
logger.info(userDetails.getUser_first_name());
logger.info("validation not working");
}
else{
logger.info("binding failure"); 
}
logger.info("setRegistration :Exit");
return null;    
}
```

> servlet-context:-

```
<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.xmith.services"/>
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.xmith.dao"/>
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.xmith.models"/>
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.xmith.sweb" />
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>
```

> dependency:-

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
<version>5.4.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

> validation class:-

```
public class UserDetails {
private String user_id;
@Size(min=3,max=7,message="user first name must have max length 7")
private String user_first_name;
private String user_last_name;
private String user_age;
private String user_email;
private String user_password;
```

**Note:-**
in above code i am trying to validate "user_first_name"(min=3,max=7,message="user first name must have max length 7"), however when i enter input more than 7 it still sets "user_first_name".

> output:---

17:33:12.399 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.resourceloading.PlatformResourceBundleLocator - ValidationMessages not found.
17:33:12.401 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.resourceloading.PlatformResourceBundleLocator - ContributorValidationMessages not found.
17:33:12.403 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.resourceloading.PlatformResourceBundleLocator - org.hibernate.validator.ValidationMessages found.
17:33:12.417 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] INFO com.xmith.sweb.HomeController - setRegistration :Entry
17:33:12.418 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] INFO com.xmith.sweb.HomeController - **binding success**
17:33:12.418 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] INFO com.xmith.sweb.HomeController - **qwertyuiiii**
17:33:12.418 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] INFO com.xmith.sweb.HomeController - **validation not working**
17:33:12.418 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] INFO com.xmith.sweb.HomeController - setRegistration :Exit

*What am i missing here?*

Comment: You're printing "binding success" and "validation not working" inside `if(bindingResult.hasErrors())`. It's just your boolean logic which is wrong.

Comment: thank. Such a lame mistake, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my boolean logic was wrong as pointed by – JB Nizet